# How To Add Session Variables with Built-In login view

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, signals

I used the built-in login view that django makes but now I don't know how to set sessions when a user logs in.  I was thinking of redirecting a user to a new view that would add these session variables but I don't see that as an ideal fix.  Another question I have is: Can I use these session variables in my templates? If not, how would I get that data to the templates?

Also I am using Django 1.11 with python 2.7.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question and show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: @MForMarlon What part? I use django.contrib.auth for my login view so I don't have a login view that's part of my problem.

Comment: I see now, perhaps similar to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652550/login-sessions-for-django

Comment: @MForMarlon That user has login in views.py, the problem I'm running into is that I don't.

Comment: @MForMarlon I added some code to my view that may be relevant. It would be cool if you could check out my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. You need to use signals. Essentially you just need to set a signal that once a user logs in, set the sessions.
Here is how it looks in my code:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def sig_user_logged_in(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    request.session['isLoggedIn'] = True
    request.session['isAdmin'] = user.is_superuser
    request.session['team'] = user.teams
    request.session['email'] = user.email
    isLoggedIn = request.session.get('isLoggedIn',False)
    isAdmin = request.session.get('isAdmin',False)
    team =request.session.get('team','')
    email = request.session.get('email','')
    return render(
        request,
        'registration/login.html',
        context = {'isLoggedIn':isLoggedIn,'isAdmin':isAdmin,'team':team,'email':email},
    )
```

Make sure to have these imports:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
```

Also if you were wondering which file I put this in, it was views.py