# Django: need Dynamic login redirect using info from database redirect after login, using built-in login

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication, get

After I login, I need to redirect to another page while adding URL parameters to the URL of the next page. I get the value of these parameters after the user is authenticated because they need to be accessed from the user database table.  I heard about using the next parameter but I don't know how I would use it since I need to access the database table and I can't do that from urls.py.  This is my url.py line for login right now:

```
    url(r'^$',auth_views.login, name='login',kwargs={
'authentication_form':loginPlaceHolderForm,
}),
```

I'm not really sure what other info you need so just ask for it in the comments and I'll be sure to add it.

Also I'm using Django 1.11

EDIT:
For more clarification: What I want is something like this /colors?team=blue

And let's say the team can be red, blue or green and you get this value from the team column in the given row that you get when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override djangos class-based view [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

In **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = loginPlaceHolderForm

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        print(self.request.user)

        # get data for user here
        user_data_query_string = ''

        url = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse('app:some-name')
            user_data_query_string)
        return url
```

In **urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766452/9225671) about adding GET querystring parameters to djangos `HttpRedirect`.

Comment: Yeah, ultimately instead of using get parameters I decided to use sessions and just save those sessions in an @receiver(user_logged_in) and then I'm able to use any value I want from the database table in any of my views.  It seemed like a more versatile solution doing it this way.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering more about the solution I used, check out this question for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533727/how-to-add-session-variables-with-built-in-login-view